# Matrix Multiplication C++

Tags: c++, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am having some trouble multiplying matrices and printing the result out. My code is as follows:

```c++
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int matArow, matAcol, matBrow, matBcol, itervar1, itervar2, itervar3, value;
    cin >> matArow >> matAcol;
    int matA[matArow][matAcol];
    for (itervar1 = 0; itervar1 < matArow; itervar1++) {
        for (itervar2 = 0; itervar2 < matAcol; itervar2++) {
            cin >> matA[itervar1][itervar2];
        }
    }
    cin >> matBrow >> matBcol;
    if (matBrow != matAcol) {
        cout << "Impossible\n";
        return 0;
    }
    int matB[matBrow][matBcol];
    for (itervar1 = 0; itervar1 < matBrow; itervar1++) {
        for (itervar2 = 0; itervar2 < matBcol; itervar2++) {
            cin >> matB[itervar1][itervar2];
        }
    }
    int matC[matArow][matBcol];
    for (itervar1 = 0; itervar1 < matArow; itervar1++) {
        for (itervar2 = 0; itervar2 < matBcol; itervar2++) {
            value = 0;
            for (itervar3 = 0; itervar3 < matAcol; itervar3++) {
                value += matA[itervar1][itervar3];
                value += matB[itervar3][itervar2];
            }
            matC[itervar1][itervar2] = value;
        }
    }
    for ( itervar1 = 0; itervar1 < matArow; itervar1++ ) {
        for ( itervar2 = 0; itervar2 < matBcol; itervar2++ ) {
            cout << matC[itervar1][itervar2] << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code doesn't return any errors, but results in incorrect matrix multiplication. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know how you run your code..but it seems you didn't compile...When compiled it threw the most readable error message possible.. "`where is arr?`"

Comment: @coderredoc I am not sure... I run it in Sublime Text 2, then it generates an executable file for my MacBookAir. I double click on this, which opens in Terminal, and runs my code.

Comment: @ArunavMAHESHWARI.: Instead of `arr` print array `C`

Comment: @ArunavMAHESHWARI -- `int matA[matArow][matAcol];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must be declared using a constant expression to denote the number of entries, not a variable.  What you're using is a non-standard extension that is offered by your compiler.  If I took your code and attempted to compile it using strict ANSI (or using Visual Studio), I would get nowhere due to the compiler errors generated on that line and lines that look like that.

Comment: @ArunavMAHESHWARI *The code doesn't return any errors,* -- [Yes it does](http://rextester.com/VPTZV6378)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie In that case, how should I multiply arbitrary matrices?

Comment: @coderredoc Thanks, but it now results in incorrect matrix multiplication... Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: @ArunavMAHESHWARI.: It's solved I guess

Comment: @ArunavMAHESHWARI -- Use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.  The `std::vector<>` is the dynamic array class that is used in C++.  In addition, writing code using the non-standard syntax you're using now gives you disadvantages.  The first being that you could cause your stack to blow up if the values you use are too large.  Second, there is no way to debug boundary conditions using that syntax.  With `std::vector`, you have `vector::at()`.  So truthfully, you're not getting any benefit (except supposedly shorter code) declaring arrays like this -- you're harming your program using it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I agree, but how can I create multi-dimensional arrays using vectors?

Comment: @ArunavMAHESHWARI `std::vector<std::vector<int>> matA(matArow, std::vector<int>(matAcol));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value += matA[itervar1][itervar3]; 
value += matB[itervar3][itervar2];`

Shouldn't it be

```
value += matA[itervar1][itervar3] * matB[itervar3][itervar2];
```